# How do you check if any of the arguments passed to function is None?

Tags: python

I have a method like

```
    @staticmethod
    def add_transaction(name, date, amount, debit, user, category_id):
        pass
```

What is the best way to test if any of them is `None`?

```
if not (name or date or amount or debit or user or category_id):
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use 'or' and not 'and'?

Comment: he wants `or` so that the `ValueError` is raised if atleast one parameter is `None`

Comment: What's your intend? Something like keyword arguments might be better!

Comment: If this were my code I would have these arguments in a list and say `if not all(list_args)`.

Comment: @squiguy: that won't distinguish between `None` and other false-like values, e.g. 0.

Comment: @DSM Ah, hints to why I put it as a comment.  I guess I was trying to be *too* concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is something you plan on using a lot, you might want to consider a decorator:

```
import functools
def None_is_dumb_and_does_not_deserve_to_enter_this_function(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args,**kwargs):
        if None in args:
            raise ValueError("None's aren't welcome here")
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return new_func

@None_is_dumb_and_does_not_deserve_to_enter_this_function
def foo(a,b,c):
    """Docstring"""
    print a,b,c

foo(1,2,3)
print foo.__doc__
foo(None,'bar','baz')
```

This still fais if you call `foo(1,2,c=3)`.  We can fix that using the [`decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module:

```
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def no_none(f,*args,**kwargs):
    if None in args:
        raise ValueError("None's aren't welcome here")
    return f(*args,**kwargs)

@no_none
def foo(a,b,c):
    """Docstring"""
    print a,b,c

foo(1,2,3)
print foo.__doc__

try:
    foo(None,'bar','baz')
except ValueError as e:
    print ('Good, raised ValueError')

try:
    foo("bar","baz",c=None)
except ValueError as e:
    print ('Good, raised ValueError')
```

Comment: @JonClements -- Thanks.  I was actually trying to figure out if I can inspect the arguments and make a `new_func` with the same signature ... but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: It's not needed for this. The only case our answers (that I can think of at the moment) will be wrong are where too many arguments are supplied and the decorator will fail it, because one of them is None, rather than the function call fail because there's too many arguments

Comment: @JonClements -- It's nice for documentation purposes and I posted an alternate case where ours will fail on your post.

Comment: Decorators are awesome, I wrote my first one from your suggestion, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

```
if any(arg is None for arg in (name, date, amount, debit, user, category_id))):
    raise ValueError("I hate None")
```

You need to test `arg is None`, rather than just using `not`. With `not`, you'll end up raising an exception if any of the arguments are `False`, `0`, `[]`, etc, which is not what you want.

@DSM's suggestion of `if None in (name, date...` works as well - it's up to you which you prefer.

Side note: your function takes a lot of arguments. I wonder if you couldn't refactor it in some way - perhaps you could make a `Transaction` class that encapsulates this data, and change this method signature to `add_transaction(transaction)`.

Comment: .. why not `None in (name, ...)`?

Comment: Because `None in (name, ...)` tests on equality, and not identity.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: if someone has perversely made an object which tests equal to `None`, who are you to gainsay him?

Comment: 6 arguments is not "a lot" and we don't have enough context to know whether adding Transaction type would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: You're right that we don't know the context; it was just a suggestion. "How many is too many" is a question of personal preference - I'd say six arguments is verging on the too-many side.

Comment: @DSM: It's not just about testing equal to None, but that testing equality is heavier and can fail etc.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: the argument that it's heavier seems silly to me-- identity is checked first before equality, so you're only losing the extra time it takes to do a failing test.  Timeit suggests the extra time is only tens of nanoseconds, or about as long as it takes to make the tuple.  I'll agree equality can fail in ways that `is` can't, but it's hard to get worked up about it.

Answer (score 5):

```
if None in (name, date, amount, debit, user, category_id):
    raise ValueError("I haz the Nones")
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use a decorator and do something like:

```
from functools import wraps

def no_none(f):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    if any(parm is None for parm in args):
      raise ValueError('None not allowed')
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper

class Testing(object):
  @staticmethod
  @no_none
  def add_transaction(name, date, amount, debit, user, category_id):
    pass

Testing.add_transaction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Testing.add_transaction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None)
```

Comment: The only problem with this (and mine) is that it breaks if the user calls the argument by keyword:  `Testing.add_transaction(1,2,3,4,5,category_id=None)`

Answer (score 1):

If None would throw an error you could just go for the function and handle the error however you wanted instead of checking ahead of time.

Comment: Upvoted - as long as your function is not a subsystem's entry point it's the caller's responsability to pass valid params.

Comment: True fact. Was [unreasonably] going on that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_transaction(**kwargs):
    if None in kwargs.values():
         raise ValueError
```

Comment: The downside is that you don't get default values for non-specified keywords or errors for invalid keywords.

Comment: downvoted - named parameters are a GoodThing(tm) for auto-documentation, and **kwargs should be reserved for either generic functions (decorators etc) or for optional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic answer is: unless it's a subsystem entry point taking data from user inputs (or another program or subsystem or a settings file etc), just *dont* waste your time with such "validation" and just use whatever was passed in. It's the caller's responsability to pass valid arguments, and if he doesn't then trying to use the arguments will raise an exception anyway.